# Zipkin not showing the microservices Sleuth logs

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, zipkin

Below is the configuration I have in the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

There are many other dependencies added in the project.

Here's the application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=order-service
server.port=9192
spring.h2.console.enable=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultzone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
#actuator settings
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.eventConsumerBufferSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.failureRateThreshold=20
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.slidingWindowSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.retry.instances.BillingServiceCapture.maxRetryAttempts=5
resilience4j.retry.instances.BillingServiceCapture.waitDuration=10s

spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
spring.zipkin.collector.http.enabled=true
```

When I send the request to the microservices - Order Service and Billing Service, I cannot see the Zipkin traces on `localhost:9411`. If I select servicename, I cannot see the microservice name in the dropdown. Any insights are useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Jonatan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929432/10231374):

> `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` is deprecated, you should not use it
> anymore. You can use `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and
> `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin` (`3.x`).

Comment: Hi @birca, thanks for the reply. Can you please point me to the documentation? I could not find Zipkin's documentation on Spring boot guide page. It does have Sleuth integration but not specifically ZIpkin. I'm aware about this: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth

Comment: Hi @Khushboo, check [Sending Spans to Zipkin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#features-zipkin) and [How to Set Up Sleuth with Brave & Zipkin via HTTP?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#how-to-set-up-sleuth-with-brave-zipkin-http).

Comment: Hi @birca123 - Thanks for sharing the documentation. I updated the dependency in the POM file however I still do not see the spans in the Zipkin. I also noted that the IDE logs doesn't show TRUE value when the Rest API is hit. Any more insights?

Comment: There is a problem related to sampling, check [the docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.1.x/multi/multi__sampling.html) and try to define a bean Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE. If this doesn't work then check if you're suddenly sending spanFlags or X-B3-Flags headers which overrides sampling decision.